# Libtool Cordova Building Failed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I seem to be getting this problem with Xcode on my Ionic based project. Does anyone know the way around this problem? I could not find any answers online regarding this issue.

```
Libtool /Users/austinsweat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Riveloper,_LLC-fftaaqxtekkzntdimgercgfdvnmb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a normal arm64
cd /Users/austinsweat/Desktop/riveloper-mobile-app-new/newApp/platforms/ios/CordovaLib
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only arm64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk -L/Users/austinsweat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Riveloper,_LLC-fftaaqxtekkzntdimgercgfdvnmb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/austinsweat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Riveloper,_LLC-fftaaqxtekkzntdimgercgfdvnmb/Build/Intermediates/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Cordova.LinkFileList -o /Users/austinsweat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Riveloper,_LLC-fftaaqxtekkzntdimgercgfdvnmb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't map file list file: /Users/austinsweat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Riveloper (Invalid argument)
```