# Cordova iOS Building Libtool Failed Error

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build the iOS  version of my Cordova app. 
I'm getting this error on Xcode for CordovaLib. i tried with different versions of cordova-ios.

This is the error log:

> Apple Mach-O Librarian (libtool) Error Group
>
> fatal error:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   can't open file list file:
>   /Users/XXX/Downloads/Staging/platforms/ios/DerivedData/APP_NAME
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> Libtool
>   /Users/XXX/Downloads/Staging/platforms/ios/DerivedData/APP_NAME/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a normal
>   x86_64

Answer (score 0):

Try with **legacy-build** mode.

```
cordova build ios --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

Comment: The following build commands failed:
 Libtool /Users/XXX/Downloads/Staging/platforms/ios/build/emulator/libCordova.a normal x86_64
(1 failure)
CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: 'Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/XXX/Downloads/Staging/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,APP_NAME.xcworkspace,-scheme,APP_NAME,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone XS Max,...... ......-UseModernBuildSystem=0'

Comment: Can't get around this, not with CLI or Xcode. Any ideas?

Comment: Xcode v10. I tried rolling back to 9.4.1. Same problem. 
Also, I found this guy was having same problem way back. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36830131/libtool-cordova-building-failed

My CordovaLib/Products/ files
cordova.framework and libCordova.a are shown in red inside Xcode files panel.